# Performance issue when query to database from rails console in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, rails-console

I develop my rails application from docker. I run `rails c` also from docker. When I try to some query like: `Patient.last` it takes about 15s-30s. I see only screen below without any message. After 15-30s record data is printed.

[image]

It occur only for models witch included devise.I have only one patient in my database. When I query again it takes milliseconds as it should.
My model definition is:
[image]

<del>My question is where problem live (AR, docker, Rails )? And how can I debug it?</del>

edit:

Thank you @Fabrizio Bertoglio for suggestion. Problem is with devise.
When I removed `devise` method from model, then patient load instantly. 
So the `devise` keyword is the problem. But why? I need to dig it, or ask in devise gem.

Comment: sorry the stupid question, have you though of somehow disabling the authentication with devise to test how fast could be the query?

Comment: No I didn't try. Thank you , It is good Idea to clear some method like devise or has_many and find out if this has performance impact.